# Create a weight with Principal Component Analysis

Tags: pca, weights

There is 50 blog's authors and a a data with three variables $v_1$,$v_2$ and $v_3$ related with these authors. In other words, I have a dataset $D=(x_{ij})_{50\times3}$. I would like to create a weight for each author and I think that I can use PCA.

Using the corresponding change of basis matrix $R$, I have

$$ R D = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
y_{11} & y_{12} & y_{13} \\
y_{21} & y_{22} & y_{23} \\
. & . & . \\
. & . & . \\
y_{50,1} & y_{50,2} & y_{50,3} \end{array} \right)$$

So, I have two questions

a) Can I use the first component of the PCA as weight, i.e, $w =\left( \begin{array}{c}
y_{11} \\
y_{21} \\
.  \\
.  \\
y_{50,1} \end{array} \right)$

b) If YES, what would be the ideal variance of this first component: 80%? 
If, for example, I obtain 60%, it would be a good index?

Comment: Can you tell us what these variables are? Are they measures of something like blog quality?